# Stop game character from moving after paused game

Tags: python, pygame

I have this 2D platformer game in PyGame where a character moves left, right and up (jump). I recently implemented a function to pause the game, which works great.

However since the code stops the character on `pygame.KEYUP` then if the user lets off the side-moving keys (A for left, D for right) AFTER they have paused the game then after resuming the character will be stuck running since it never got the KEYUP event.

Any ideas that makes the character stop X-axis movement after pause? Thankful for any help!

Pause function:

```
def game_pause:
    pause = True
    while pause == True:
        pygame.init()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    pause = False
```

Main
loop:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        
        #---Key presses---
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.go_left()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.go_right()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.jump()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                game_pause()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a and player.change_x < 0:
                player.stop()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d and player.change_x > 0:
                player.stop()
```

Functions that moves the player-class:

```
    def go_left(self):
        self.change_x = -5
    def go_right(self):
        self.change_x = 5
    def stop(self):
        self.change_x = 0
```

Comment: Call `player.stop()` when you set `pause = True`. If you do not want to stop the player, you must process the `KEYUP` event in pause mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set

```
pause = False
```

in the main loop and in the go_left(), go_right(), stop() functions make an if statement like

```
 def go_left(self):
    if not pause :
        self.change_x = -5
```

so when you pause the game the if statement becomes false